# Using FileHistory on Windows 8 to backup to a specific folder on a network drive

Tags: windows-8, backup, file-history

How can I backup my windows 8.1 desktop to a specific folder on a network drive using the built in FileHistory? The entire drive is not just for my backup, so I want to backup under a specific folder:

```
Z:/mynetworkpiece/desktopBU/{BACKUP HERE}
```

But FileHistory seems to only lets me choose the entire drive, meaning it tries to create the backup at the root `Z:/` as such

```
Z:/{BACKUP HERE}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to select or create a directory to use when adding a network location. If you're selecting an existing one try and create a new one.

Also, win8 is strange in that it has FileHistory and SystemRecovery instead of 7's Backup and Restore wizard. It sounds like its file history you want though.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have z: mapped to \\server\myshare create another mapping to the folder where you want to store the backups. For instance you can map Y: to \\server\myshare\desktopBU then configure the backup for the y: drive.

Answer (score 0):

To rephrase what @Bin said, you can map a drive deeper inside a shared path than its root.  For instance, let's say you have a server SERVER, which has a share SHARE, which has a folder FOLDER inside, which has another folder DESKTOPBU inside.  On the desktop, map Y: to \SERVER\SHARE\FOLDER\DESKTOPBU and set it to reconnect Y: every time you log in.  Now, start your FileHistory again, and tell it to use Y: .